# Адресация команды platform.system() сетевой машине

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как адресовать команду `platform.system()` сетевой машине , чтобы получить имя системы, ведь она не принимает аргументов?
например, команда `socket.getfqdn(ipaddress)`, принимает адрес и возвращает имя хоста.
Или в общем вопрос, как адресовывать команды без аргументов (например, os.name()) сетевым устройствам, чтобы получать информацию от них?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, разобрался. platform.system() выполняется на локальной машине и к сетевому устройству не применимо.

Comment: `socket.getfqdn(ipaddress)` также на локальной машине исполняется (может выполнить сетевой запрос к dns-серверу (не имеет отношения к машине с `ipaddress`), но не обязательно).